# Installing OpenWRT in TPLink Archer C50

Tags: router, openwrt, firmware

I bought a TP-Link Archer C50 after reading that OpenWRT supported it. Now I'm not finding the right version of the firmware I should download.

Information I got from [Official page in OpenWRT for Archer C50](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c50)

> It is similar to Archer C20i and C20
>
> System-On-Chip: **MediaTek MT7620A**
>
> Target: **ramips**

And then a few links:

- [Archer C50 tech page](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/tp-link/tp-link_archer_c50_v1): where I didn't find any new info.
- [Firmware OpenWrt Install URL](http://openrouter.info/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41591#p41591): goes to a polish forum that I tried to understand translating it but the link with the firmware I thought I should download was actually a file named `ArcherC50V1_tp_recovery.bin` which seems to be to debrick the router.
- [Firmware OpenWrt Upgrade URL](http://dl.eko.one.pl/luci/chaos_calmer/ramips/luci-15.05-ramips-mt7620-ArcherC50-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin): which doesn't seem to be what I want since its to upgrade OpenWrt and I still haven't installed it.
- [Obtaining Firmware](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/obtain.firmware): from this page I went to `Download page` -> `latest version` -> `Download server` -> `Chaos Calmer 15.05.1` -> `ramips` (the routers target) -> `mt7620` (MediaTek MT7620A, the routers chip). In that page I found a lot of options and I could relate some of them with my router: those which included `mt7620a` in the name and one that said `ArcherC20i`, but all of them were `sysupgrade`.

Which `.bin` should I use to install OpenWRT for the first time?

Comment: I have bad news for you.  Your router is only supported by a third-party build of OpenWRT.  So the forum link you provide, that is the bin your suppose to use, once you use that you can use the upgrade bin.

Comment: OK, so I should use the TFTP method described in the polish forum and then upgrade to an official `.bin`? In that case, which `.bin`?

Comment: I suggest not using OpenWRT since its not officially supported.  There is no "official" version of OpenWRT that supports your router, its only a third-party, who made modifications.  I can't support OpenWRT for one simple reasons, it has been forked, and all the good developers went to the fork (LEDE).  I can't visit the link, I also can't read polish, so use the method described by the only instructions that exist.

Comment: I didn't know LEDE project. I've just checked it out and I found there is a specific version for Archer C50, but the only `.bin` available is for `sysupgrade`. How should I install it for the first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [installation section of its page](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer-c50#installation):

> - **Supported Current Rel:** external image
> - **Firmware OpenWrt Install URL:** http://openrouter.info/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41591#p41591

At that link, there are step-by-step instructions in Polish that can be translated by e.g. Google Translate:

> Download crafted recovery of OpenWrt:
>   <url>
>
> 1. Set up tftp server providing the file.
> 2. Set the IP address on the network server to 192.168.0.66
> 3. Turn off the router.
> 4. Connect the computer / server to the LAN port on the router.
> 5. Press and hold the reset button / wps.
> 6. Turn on the router and wait until WPS LED will light - about 8 seconds.
> 7. Began recovery procedure.
> 8. Release the reset / wps.
> 9. Wait about 60 seconds.
>
> Finished!!

The image is called "recovery" because you're using a "recovery mode" of that router to install it.